# The expected number of n types of coupons have appeared at least once?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

There are **n** different types of coupons and each item must contain one coupon. So what is the expected number of items needed to buy for **all n types of coupons** have appeared at **least once**?

Comment: See the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).